# ADB command to toggle video from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: adb

I am playing a video through adb on my device. but it plays in portrait mode by default.
Is there any adb command to toggle the video in landscape mode automatically.

Comment: Can you more describe your problem? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)